# Question regarding interpretation of ARDL results - logged & first differenced variables

Tags: interpretation, ardl

I have trouble understanding how I should interpret my results from ARDL regression.
Does anyone know how the following table should be interpreted?

d indicating first difference,
ln indicating log
(hence, realinterest is not transformed)
[image]

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to CV, Hampus.  There's a lot going on in this table and a lot more that you know about the variables but haven't revealed.  So, at one and the same time there's too much for us to reply to and not enough.  Could you perhaps clarify what kind of interpretation you are looking for?